# I am unable to ping to the manual proxy from a node

Tags: networking, proxy, ping, cpan, hpc

I am using a HPC system with a master node and 8 other compute nodes. I have to download a LibXML perl module using CPAN on each of the compute nodes.

I am able to ping the proxy from the master node. But, I am unable to do it from the compute nodes. It is because of this reason that while installing the module from CPAN, the proxy barrier is causing problems.

How exactly do i connect to the internet, bypassing the proxy from the compute nodes?

Answer (score 0):

For cluster nodes on a private network to make contact with external machines and the Internet you need to setup Network Address Translation. How you go about doing this will depend on what OS you are using on your cluster.

Comment: Just want to follow up by mentioning that other options do exist to grant cluster nodes access to external content. For me, NAT seems like the solution that you could gain the most by implementing. You could also mirror CPAN and other repositories on your head node or setup a caching proxy to speed up installs across multiple nodes. Numerous options exist, you just need to figure out what fits your environment(cluster, organizational network/LAN, WAN link) the best.